# Avoid using pandas for csv editing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am using pandas to load, modify and save csv files. Actually pandas and its dataframe functionality is only a workaround for me, as I do not need this. I only need it, because I have to modify my csv file.

I need to remove certain lines (rows). My current code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
test=pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', sep=';', skiprows=[0,1,3,4,6])
test.to_csv('myoutputfile.csv', index=False, sep=';')
```

I would like to maniuplate the csv file directly. I know that with `import csv` and `next(reader)` I could for example skip the first row. However, I need to skip these specific rows: `skiprows=[0,1,3,4,6]` and I don't know how to do this. So is there a way to modify the csv files without using pandas and save the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally, if you have a list of rows to skip, you can use something like this:

```
import csv

skiprows = (0,1,3,4,6)
with open('myfile.csv') as fp_in:
    reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter=';')
    rows = [row for i, row in enumerate(reader) if i not in skiprows]
    with open('myoutputfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp_out:
        writer = csv.writer(fp_out)
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and +1. However, my problem is that the header is not in the first row. So the header, the column names are in the third row that is why number 2 is not in the list in skiprows. How can I do this? Currently when I run your code, row 0 is taken as the header? I tried to just remove the fieldnames=header and header = reader.fieldnames, but then I get an error message. Actually I do not need to care about this: So I only want row 0,1,3,4,6 to be removed. Then row 2 will automatically stay and become the new first row in my output file. So that is all I want.

Comment: Furthermore when I check the resulting files there are now empty lines added into the data?

Comment: @BertHobe, I updated the code, so it does not read the header separately.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but now I get an error header not defined? I guess this is because fieldnames is still set to header.

Comment: Yes, just need to remove fieldnames at all. Updated by answer

Comment: @BertHobe, added a fix for empty lines.